# Автоматическое добавление класса "expired" по истечению дня

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Я сделал календарь на HTML & CSS но мне не хватает JS (или jQuery) для того, чтобы по истечению определённого времени даты становились неактивными. Все неактивные кнопки (с датами) имеют класс "expired" и мне необходимо чтобы по истечению каждого дня к каждой следующей кнопке добавлялся класс "expired".

Сам календарь тут:
https://coralife.cf/calendar/

```
 <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
   </colgroup>
   <tr class="head-of-calendar">
      <th class="tg-kt03">Пн</th>
      <th class="tg-kt03">Вт</th>
      <th class="tg-kt03">Ср</th>
      <th class="tg-kt03">Чт</th>
      <th class="tg-kt03">Пт</th>
      <th class="tg-kt03">Сб</th>
      <th class="tg-kt03">Вс</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">1</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">2</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">3</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">4</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">5</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">6</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">7</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">8</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">9</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">10</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">11</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">12</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">13</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">14</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">15</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">16</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">17</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">18</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">19</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Сегодня 20 июля. День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num active" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">20</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">21</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">22</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">23</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">24</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">25</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">26</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">27</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">28</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">29</button></td>
      <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">30</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Вот ссылка **https://coralife.cf/%D1%81alendar/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, не существует события, которое бы отвечало за изменение даты. Поэтому, как вариант, могу предложить фрагмент кода, который с определённой периодичностью (в данном случае - 1 секунда) сравнивает текущий день со всеми значениями innerHTML кнопок и добавляет класс expired, если значение кнопки меньше текущего дня месяца:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        let buttons = document.body.querySelectorAll("td button");
        refreshButtons();
        setInterval(()=> {
            refreshButtons();
        },1000);
        function refreshButtons() {
            let currDay = new Date().getDate();
            buttons.forEach((btn)=>{
                if (parseInt(btn.innerHTML)<currDay) {
                    btn.classList.add("expired")
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

Какие тут есть подвохи:

1. Ваша таблица показывает только один месяц. Если этот функцонал расширять на любое количество месяцев/лет, то этот скрипт придётся модифицировать и способ хранения даты для каждой из кнопок необходимо будет поменять (например - добавить кастомный аттрибут)
2. Наверняка далее будет происходить связь с сервером, у которого может быть другое локальное время и поэтому ваш скрипт должен будет ориентироваться на него. Т.е. либо с определённой периодичностью опрашивать сервер на предмет его локального времени (что есть нехорошо), либо отлавливать изменение даты сервера (оптимально, но не факт, что у сервера есть такая возможность).